# How to get Magento 2 secure base URL?

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm using below code to get base url in magento 2.

```
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
echo $baseurl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
```

Let me know how to get secure base url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct, just pass the second parameter boolean `true` with `getBaseUrl()` method, by default its null, use below code like :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
echo $baseurl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB); 
echo $secureBaseUrl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
echo $secureBaseUrl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB,true);
```